# SVG line animation with anime.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, svg

I'm modifying a pen to create an SVG animation. I would like the green element to exactly follow the line path but it is not. Also it is not looping the 8 path correctly in one line but bounceing at the crossroad of the loop. Any advice how to achieve this would be appreciated since I haven't been able to find a solution

```
var path = anime.path('path');

anime({
  targets: 'div',
  translateX: path,
  translateY: path,
  rotate: path,
  duration: 6000,
  loop: true,
  easing: 'linear'
});
```

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWYKwB

Answer (score 2):

A few days ago I told you that your path has a problem.
You have to rebuild your path ...

```html
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head> 
  <body>
    <button onclick="dashAni(myPath, 50, 3500)">start</button>
    <svg id="mySVG"  width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
        <path id="myPath" d="M 50,250 c 0 -100   150 -100   200 0 
                                      c 50 100   200 100   200 0
                                      c -0 -100   -150 -100   -200 0
                                      c -50 100   -200 100   -200 0
                                      z" 
        stroke="#eee"
        stroke-width="5" fill="none" />
    </svg>
    <script>
      var dashAni = function(path, length, duration){
        var dashPath = path.cloneNode(true);
        mySVG.appendChild(dashPath);
        var pathLen=path.getTotalLength();  
        var aktPos=0
        var sumSteps = duration / (1000/60) // 60 pics per second
        var step=0;
        var pathAnim;
        dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', length + ' ' + (pathLen - length));
        dashPath.setAttribute('stroke', "red");
        dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', aktPos);

        var anim=function(){
           aktPos = pathLen/sumSteps*step*-1;
            //aktLen = easeInOutQuad(step/sumSteps)*len;
           dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', length + ' ' + pathLen);
           dashPath.setAttribute('stroke-dashoffset', aktPos);

           if (step <= (sumSteps)){
            step++;
            pathAnim = setTimeout(anim, 1000/60) //1000/60 pics/second
            } else {
              mySVG.removeChild(dashPath);
              clearTimeout(pathAnim);
            }
        }
       anim();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I made it into a single path, but it's still not working. I should be able to add your path aswell into my code but the line still does not follow the path correctly. Can you elaborate on what is wrong with my path, since it should be a single path now (one M only). Here is added your path: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VWYKwB

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not tell you, because I rarely work with libraries. The time to deal with such libs is too big for me, so I write the routines I always need myself.